# SVN Subclipse : Not working for googlecode

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I am trying to connect to google code giving http://birdeye.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ as the URL. it is not connecting and gives the following error.

"The VCC property was not found on the resource"

Any ideas or thoughts how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to connect via `https://`.

Try connecting to `https://birdeye.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/`

Comment: It depends - the url would be the https:// if he has commit access to the repo in question. Otherwise the anonymous access repos are available only via http://

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was using the incorrect password. You need to look here: https://code.google.com/hosting/settings for the password.